# Question about Convergence with series

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis, convergence-divergence

Why does $\sum\limits_{k=1}^{\infty} \dfrac{1}{k^2}$ converge but $\sum\limits_{k=1}^{\infty} \dfrac{1}{k}$ not?

I know theres a theorem that tells me, if a series converge, then the members are a null sequence. This applies correctly to this situation. I guess this theorem won't work the other way around.

Also I looked at the Cauchy criterion which tells me that a series convergences exactly then when for all $\epsilon > 0$ an index $N \geq 1$ exists so that: $\mid \sum\limits_{k=n+1}^{m} a_k \mid < \epsilon, \quad m > n \geq N $.

Lets think about that. I tried to apply this to our situation and it shouldn't work but in my eye's it works because:

$\dfrac{1}{1},\dfrac{1}{2},\dfrac{1}{3},\dfrac{1}{4},...$

here applies the Cauchy criterion because the difference is getting smaller and smaller.

$\dfrac{1}{1},\dfrac{1}{4},\dfrac{1}{9},\dfrac{1}{16},...$

this is also the case for $\dfrac{1}{k^2}$

I guess there must be a mistake at the point there i try to use the Cauchy criterion.

Comment: you've put the same series twice

Answer (score 2):

The Cauchy criterion does *not* apply to $\sum \frac 1k$. We may choose $m, n$ arbitrarily far apart, just as long as both of them are larger than $N$. If we choose them far enough apart, we can make $\sum_{k = n+1}^m \frac1k$ as large as we want, no matter how large a lower bound $N$ we place on $m$ and $n$. For instance, if $m$ is larger than $2n$, then the sum becomes greater than $\frac12$. If $m$ is larger than $4n$, the sum becomes larger than $1$. And so on.

Answer (score 0):

That the difference is getting smaller - that is a necessary condition, not a sufficient condition. And this is exactly the obvious counter-example.

Comment: hm, why is this not an answer?

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**. One has, as $N \to \infty$,
$$
\int_1^N \frac1{x^2}\:dx=1-\frac1N \to 1
$$ whereas
$$
\int_1^N \frac1{x}\:dx=\log N \to \infty
$$ then use the [integral test for convergence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integral_test_for_convergence) respectively for $\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac1{n^2}$ and for $\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac1{n}$.